# How to update label box from selection of listbox using math

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have 2 list boxes within my form. Listbox1 contains different types of items that have a price and Listbox2 contains how much of that item you want to purchase. How do I update my price label so when I select both options from each list box it updates the label and gives me a price. Here's an example to help you better understand.

I select the $1.50 Chocolate Chip Cookie item in my ListBox1 and in ListBox2 I select the 1 Dozen Cookie item. So I would want my priceLabel to update to $18.00. How would I do this?

As of now I have tried creating some code in the `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method but I am returned these 3 following values... `$0.00`...`$2.00`...`$4.00`

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double index = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            double index2 = listBox2.SelectedIndex;
            double total = index * index2;
            label9.Text = total.ToString("C");
        }

        private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            const int ESTIMATED_ARRIVAL = 3;
            label10.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.AddDays(ESTIMATED_ARRIVAL).ToShortDateString();
        }

        private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the ".SelectedIndex" property only returns a 0-index position of the currently selected item in the listbox. That's why the calculation goes wrong.

I would like to suggest the use of the ".SelectedItem" property. Because it returns the selected item itself instead of it's postition. So if your items contain a double value, then the calculation will succeed.